# Prove Convergence in Probability is closed under multiplication

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

This seems like a pretty plain question, but I can't figure it out.

Let $X_n \to X$ in probability, and $Y_n \to Y$ in probability. Show that $X_N Y_N \to XY$ in probability.

So far I can only show the case where $X = Y = 0$ for all $\omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$X_N Y_N - X Y= X (Y_N - Y) + (X_N - X)(Y_N - Y)
+ (X_N - X) Y$$  Take $M$ such that with
probability $> 1-\epsilon$, $|X| < M$ and $|Y| < M$...

Comment: Countable additivity, really: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(n \le |X| < n+1) = P\left(\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty (n \le |X| < n+1)\right) = 1$$